# What will happen to my App by Device Reset Date?

Tags: ios, xcode

My Apple developer membership will expire in several days. So I renewed my membership just now. But I found **Device Reset Date** remained at August 27, 2016. It's the first time I renew my Apple membership. I don't know what I should do with my App. Should I renew my profiles/certificates? If yes, will my online Apps be able to receive remote notifications?

Comment: That will allow you to remove devices that you’ve directly run on from Xcode, freeing up more of your limit of 99.

Answer (score 4):

You will be presented with the option to reset your device list on that day...because you have a 100 device limit, you may wish to remove devices that are no longer being used for testing.